# What is mean by short circuit voltage

Tags: circuit-analysis

What is mean by short circuit voltage in Electrical Engineering

Comment: A short circuit, by definition has no voltage.

Comment: the phrase short circuit **current** is in common use, as is open circuit voltage. Swapping them about leaves something meaningless.

Comment: Unless you can provide a reference or two, it seems doubtful that the term "short circuit voltage" is actually used in Electrical Engineering. Because it basically doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 1):

The is no standard expression "short circuit voltage"in electrical engineering. However there are other related expressions like;

Short circuit

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short_circuit

Short circuit current

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prospective_short_circuit_current

Breakdown voltage

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breakdown_voltage

Electrical breakdown

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_breakdown

In my ears "short circuit voltage" could imply the voltage at which one or more components in a circuit breaks down resulting in a potential short circuit. However there is no such term that is widely used.